# How did the convention of not puttting any whitespace in Obj-C method declarations come about?

Tags: objective-c, coding-style

How did it become convention that there is no whitespace in the declaration of a method?

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
```

It seems like everyone does it, 90% of the examples I see, the generated templates, other people's code, etc., etc. I suspect it's just another vi/emacs ideological thing, but wondered if maybe there was a K&R kind of "root cause" to the behavior.

Me, I like lots of whitespace:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath
```

This seems so much better to me.

Comment: Hey. You're right. Project Builder (before Xcode) even had a preference setting that would automatically align the colons for you. I can't find that in Xcode - at least not where it used to be. I never noticed the transition. But now I miss it.

Comment: @No one in particular - I can't find the automatic setting either, although, if you hit Return after a parameter, it will line up the colons for that line. Still obnoxious, but if you really miss it, file a Radar for it (http://bugreport.apple.com). Xcode 4 is in active development right now...maybe they can sneak it in :)

Comment: Your example is actually missing more whitespace than is common. Signatures generally use types like `(UITableView *)` (note the space), as well as a space after the leading -. In any case, there's two possible causes. The first is people who don't hard-wrap until the line passes a certain length (e.g. people like me), and the second is a large number of Obj-C engineers these days just turn on Xcode's soft-wrapping and never hard-wrap lines at all.

Comment: I have found that for selector declarations I use two spaces between argument clauses and a space after the return type, i.e.: `- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath`.  I find this groups things nicely, but that's just my approach.

Comment: I've long thought that the visual appearance of their code comes up short. Their stinginess with whitespace is a big part of it. It surprises me, considering how much attention to detail is applied to their products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know a lot of code styles take getting used to to be more understandable.  In this case I think that Apple's syntax reflects a thought process more than a coding style, not just personal preference.

When I first started using Objective-C I had the same concern.  It can be confusing to look at no whitespace in a long line of code.  However, once you get a better feel for the syntax, you will notice that even in your example there is whitespace.  It's used to separate the segments of the function names from the previous parameter.  Once you're there it becomes easier to pick out each segment of the function and it's parameter.  Function name segment on the left, param on the right, repeat.

At first I did what you have listed -- spaces after everything.  However that ended up being almost as bad as no whitespace.  Since there were spaces everywhere they became meaningless.  I next tried putting spaces after the colon and after the param, but that didn't seem right either -- the function name and the parameters started to get confusing in some cases.  I tried a few other whitespace styles and eventually came back to use apple's standard almost exactly.  The only thing I differ on now is the return type -- I prefer to have a space after the + or - and a space after the return type.  Even that isn't that big of a deal, being mostly personal preference rather than any specific difficulty.  (Having a heavy C/C++ background I like to be able to see the return type at a glance.)

If you keep at it you'll suddenly find yourself liking apple's way over the other.  =)

Answer (score 2):

Most selectors are short enough that you don't need to put every argument on it's own line. It needs some getting used to, but without the spaces, the readability then becomes actually much better. Compare:

```
- (id) actionWithParam: (id) param object: (id) someObject andMore: (id) another

- (id)actionWithParam:(id)param object:(id)someObject andMore:(id)another
```

In the first line your brain will group stuff like

```
param object: (id)
```

which doesn't belong together, while in the second version you got the parameter groups nicely separated by whitespaces. The groups are pretty dense in themselves now, but the colon and parantheses actually are enough to separate name from the parameter and type.

Comment: Thanks for the comment w.m. I can see your point about short selector and type names. Cramming them together does group them unambiguously.

Not sure if I agree with how my brain will group things, mine doesn't seem to do any coherent grouping, even with the no-whitespace version, I just spend a lot of time reading it. And it's particularly a problem with long type names, as you see in Cocoa in many classes, particularly the delegate protocols where the first param is an object context, repeated throughout the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Good practices in Objective-C say than each method should contain a predicate and a sort of description of its parameters (tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) hence the parameters are usually tied up with the previous part of the method name.
Hope this makes sense.